# Request url on my Slack app that is invoked on clicking a button requires basic auth

Tags: http-post, basic-authentication, slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I have defined a request URL which gets triggerred whenever I click a button in my Slack channel.(** From the docs - Any interactions with shortcuts, modals, or interactive components (such as buttons, select menus, and datepickers) will be sent to a URL you specify.**). However, I require basic auth to send post requests to this URL. Hence, I keep getting a 401 unauthorized error whenever I do a POST request.

I do not see any way to add these authorization details anywhere in my slack app configurations. How do I make a request to this URL? Is there an alternative way to add the authorization header to this POST request?

Comment: Did you ever find an auth solution for this? I'm running into the same issue.. I see no way to provide slack with a token or auth headers...

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a button on Slack, there is no authentication from the part of Slack.
Slack is simply acting as a frontend, sending a request.
The 401 error is coming from your backend and depends fully on your implementation (where the url is pointing to)

Comment: note: if you think a question needs more detail/clarity, you are discouraged from answering it until that detail/clarity is added. see [answer].